# How to pass an object to controller using ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass an object to controller and retrieve the values in the controller.
I have defined like:

Html code:

```
 var positionarray = [];
```

Javascript:

```
 $("#button").live('click',function(){
     positionarray.push({
         id: sessionStorage.getItem('id'),
         value: $("#input").val() 
     });
 });

 // on save button click
 $.ajax({
       type: "GET",                                                 
       url:"/Bugs/Position",                                                 
       data: {
           array:positionarray      
       },
       cache: false,
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function (json) {

       }
 });
```

But i am not able to retrieve the values in the controller. It is getting null.

Comment: how does your action look like?

Comment: Print your `Request` at `/Bugs/Position` page, and check what you get, I think its correct.

Comment: I am able to pass to the controller but the values that are getting in the controller are null

Comment: @Naidu You are passing an array, can you do Post instead of GET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:- You are passing an array of objects so you should do HTTPPost rather than HttpGet (this will work for array of primitive types say list of int, strgin etc) sending it through query string(Remember the limit for query string).
Try this with HTTPPost

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",                     
       url:"Home/Position",                                                 
       data: JSON.stringify({
              array: positionarray
       }),
       cache: false,
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function (json) {

       }

[HTTPPost]
public void Position(YourClass[] array){...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",                                                 
       url:"/Bugs/Position",                                                 
       data: 'array='+positionarray      
       cache: false,
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function (json) {

       }
});
```

Comment: Pass it as string instead of an object. I got a feeling that given your array is of JSON type, it's malforming the data object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your `ajax call` must be in button click function then it will work,

In your code your `ajax call` runs before your click so it will pass **null** 
to your **controller**

```
$("#button").live('click',function(){
     positionarray.push({
         id: sessionStorage.getItem('id'),
         value: $("#input").val() 
     });


    // on save button click
    // this code must run after `button click` and after pushing data in
    // positionarray variable
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",                                                 
           url:"/Bugs/Position",                                                 
           data: {
               array:positionarray      
           },
           cache: false,
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function (json) {

           }
    });// here ajax function code ends

});// here button click function ends
```

Comment: @Naidu Check once, in your `question` your `ajax code` is outside the `button click function`.

Comment: But i have written an comment that ajax will be in button click

Comment: Its true but comments will not work (`code matters`), before your comment you have closed the `button click function` by using `});`. Test my answer first and come with some output.

Comment: There are two button's here. In the first button i am adding the values and in the second button i am saving. I am sorry that i was not clear. The problem is cleared now. Json.stringify will do the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**My Example :**

```
// Class
    namespace Bookstore.ViewModels {
        public class ShoppingViewModel {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int quentity { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

---

```
/// Shopping Cart
$(function () {
    $(".Quantity").on("click", function () {
        debugger
        var model = {};
        model.id = parseInt($(this).val());
        model.quentity = parseInt($(this).next().val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Cart/ModifiedCart",
            data:model,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ModifiedCart(ShoppingViewModel model)
        {
            return Json(model);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add traditional:true to ajax function!!!!!

Comment: Welcome! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and improve your answer.