# AJAX send null on my VW in controller

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax

Good evening SO, this been bugging me for a few hours already and still haven't figure out how to fix this.

All of my request data is fine except for **subscriptionTag**, it's value is always null whenever i send the request to server. I even tried removing JSON.stringify but it gives me false value instead.

**Edit** : Added HTTPPost in controller and type: post in javascript, i'm having an 500(internal server error) now :(

**Edit 2** : Added Request Payload and Request URL
Request URL: http://localhost:49895/exclusive/send

Request Payload:
`subscriptionTag=%7B%22IsAutomotive%22%3Atrue%2C%22IsMusicandDance%22%3Afalse%2C%22IsBeautyLifestyle%22%3Atrue%2C%22IsNighlifeEvent%22%3Afalse%2C%22IsFashion%22%3Afalse%2C%22IsRestaurantBar%22%3Afalse%2C%22IsHealthAndFitness%22%3Afalse%2C%22IsSportsOutdoor%22%3Afalse%2C%22IsHomeDecor%22%3Afalse%2C%22IsTravel%22%3Afalse%7D&pageid=33&emailAddress=gabyap1390%40gmail.com&token=cz0xJmV4Y2x1c2l2ZUlkPTM20&FirstName=Gabriel&source=%2Fsiggpay&MembershipLevelId=33`

.NET

```
`
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("~/exclusive/send")]
 public JsonResult Send(SubscriptionTag subscriptionTag, int pageid, string EmailAddress, string token, string FirstName = "", string source = "", int? MembershipLevelId = null)
 {
     return Json(new { error = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

`

JAVASCRIPT

```
var subscriptionTag = {};
subscriptionTag.IsAutomotive = $('#IsAutomotive').is(":checked");
subscriptionTag.IsMusicandDance = $('#IsMusicandDance').is(":checked");
subscriptionTag.IsBeautyLifestyle = $('#IsBeautyLifestyle').is(":checked");
subscriptionTag.IsNighlifeEvent = $('#IsNighlifeEvent').is(":checked");
subscriptionTag.IsFashion = $('#IsFashion').is(":checked");
subscriptionTag.IsRestaurantBar = $('#IsRestaurantBar').is(":checked");
subscriptionTag.IsHealthAndFitness = $('#IsHealthAndFitness').is(":checked");
subscriptionTag.IsSportsOutdoor = $('#IsSportsOutdoor').is(":checked");
subscriptionTag.IsHomeDecor = $('#IsHomeDecor').is(":checked");
subscriptionTag.IsTravel = $('#IsTravel').is(":checked");

$.ajax({

    url: MyAppUrlSettings.MyUsefulUrl,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        subscriptionTag: JSON.stringify(subscriptionTag),
        pageid: pageid,
        emailAddress: emailAddress,
        token: token,
        FirstName: firstName,
        source: source,
        MembershipLevelId: membershipLevelId
    },

    success: function (result) {
        if (result.error == false)
            location.href = ""
    }

});
```

},`

Just in case you might ask, heres my query string parameters.

`subscriptionTag: {"IsAutomotive":false,"IsMusicandDance":false,"IsBeautyLifestyle":true,"IsNighlifeEvent":true,"IsFashion":false,"IsRestaurantBar":true,"IsHealthAndFitness":true,"IsSportsOutdoor":false,"IsHomeDecor":false,"IsTravel":false}
pageid: 33
emailAddress: gabyap1390@gmail.com
token: cz0xJmV4Y2x1c2l2ZUlkPTM20
FirstName: Gabriel
source: /siggpay
MembershipLevelId: 33`

Comment: You need to use `method: 'POST'` inside your ajax statement, otherwise it defaults to a GET request, which only gets data, but can't send along a payload to the server, so your code currently sends NO DATA!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an object to controller using ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271404/how-to-pass-an-object-to-controller-using-ajax-call)

Comment: @TJBlackman, i tried adding that and [HttpPost] in my controller, my controller is not being call after that.

Comment: don't edit the question to include the solution. it obscures the original issue for future readers. Instead post the solution in the Answers section, separately. This site follows a "question" and "answer" format. Leave your question as a question and post your answer as an answer. You're even allowed to "accept" your own answer as the best. In future others may then upvote it, if they find it helpful to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who commented on this but I managed to fix my problem I change my data from

```
data: {
     subscriptionTag: JSON.stringify(subscriptionTag),
     <code>some code here</code>
 },
```

into

```
data: JSON.stringify({
     subscriptionTag: subscriptionTag,
     <code>some code here</code>
 }),
```